# The NIST randomness tests for a generated key

Tags: random, key, nist

Does different tests for key randomness provided by NIST are available online? where one can test that which test for key generated are passed and which are failed?

Comment: or is there any matlab program available where we can put input sequence and outputs different test results.

Comment: I found this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147142 . It's a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no randomness tests for *keys*, and in fact there will probably never be. The reason is that randomness tests require a huge amount of input to function, often on the order of gigabytes, so a single key can never be tested. What randomness tests are for is to ensure that hardware noise sources and PRNG algorithms are generating pseudorandom and uniformly-distributed output.

Comment: thanks for you answer,, But if you consider physical layer security methods, where in literature it is defined that the xyz quantizer can generate 128 bit key length, and then different NIST randomness test are applied on it to prove that it's random. e.g monobit test, runs test, block frequency test etc.. Sorry if question is silly being new to it.

Comment: @WBAN_crypto Those tests simply don't work on input that small.

Comment: thanks, some of the test I think work having  $K_{length}\geq 100$